Set fontsize of axis and legends in seaborn.objects
I am using seaborn.objects to create a faceted plot. I have read the documentation but setting font size argument does not do anything (Seaborn.objects Documentation)
My Df:
{'storage': {0: '4 °C',
  1: '4 °C',
  2: 'fresh',
  3: 'fresh',
  4: 'frozen',
  5: 'frozen',
  6: '4 °C',
  7: '4 °C',
  8: 'fresh',
  9: 'fresh',
  10: 'frozen',
  11: 'frozen',
  12: '4 °C',
  13: '4 °C',
  14: 'fresh',
  15: 'fresh',
  21: 'fresh'},
 'time': {0: '4 h',
  1: '6 h',
  2: '4 h',
  3: '6 h',
  4: '4 h',
  5: '6 h',
  6: '4 h',
  7: '6 h',
  8: '4 h',
  9: '6 h',
  10: '4 h',
  11: '6 h',
  12: '4 h',
  13: '6 h',
  14: '4 h',
  15: '6 h',
  21: '6 h'},
 'Predicted Class': {0: 'resting',
  1: 'resting',
  2: 'resting',
  3: 'resting',
  4: 'resting',
  5: 'resting',
  6: 'swollen',
  7: 'swollen',
  8: 'swollen',
  9: 'swollen',
  10: 'swollen',
  11: 'swollen',
  12: 'germling',
  13: 'germling',
  14: 'germling',
  15: 'germling',
  21: 'hyphae'},
 '%': {0: 25.57,
  1: 4.87,
  2: 12.19,
  3: 4.87,
  4: 99.87,
  5: 99.77,
  6: 72.89,
  7: 60.23,
  8: 86.93,
  9: 42.83,
  10: 0.13,
  11: 0.23,
  12: 1.54,
  13: 34.9,
  14: 0.88,
  15: 51.4,
  21: 0.9}}

import seaborn.objects as so
    
    
    # Create the Plot object
    plot = so.Plot(counts2_melted_df, x="storage", y="%", color="Predicted Class", text="%")
    
    # Facet the plot by 'strain' with an increased height for each row
    plot = plot.layout(size=(8,8)) # Adjust the scale factor for height
    
    # Add the bar and stack
    plot = plot.add(so.Bar(), so.Stack()).scale(color=color_palette)
    
    plot = plot.label(x="Storage Condition", y="Percentage of Morphotype (%)")
    
    plot= plot.theme({"axes.facecolor": "w", "axes.edgecolor": "slategray"})
    
    plot = plot.facet(row="time")
    
    #Render the plot to get the underlying matplotlib axes
    plot.plot()

I have tried
    plot = plot.label(x="Storage Condition", fontsize=28)
 plot = plot.label(y="Percentage of Morphotype (%)", fontsize=28)

Any suggestions? I need to increase the font size drastically to make the plot readable on a poster.
I would be grateful for any help!

You are trying to use the fontsize argument within the label method of seaborn.objects to change the font size, but this won't work because seaborn.objects has a different approach to styling and theming than traditional matplotlib or the older seaborn API.
Instead, you need to use the .theme method to control the appearance of elements in a seaborn.objects plot, including the font size. Here's how you can do it:
import seaborn.objects as so

plot = so.Plot(counts2_melted_df, x="storage", y="%", color="Predicted Class", text="%")

plot = plot.layout(size=(8, 8))
plot = plot.add(so.Bar(), so.Stack()).scale(color=color_palette)
plot = plot.label(x="Storage Condition", y="Percentage of Morphotype (%)")

# Customize theme with larger font sizes
plot = plot.theme({
    "axes.facecolor": "w",
    "axes.edgecolor": "slategray",
    "xtick.labelsize": 20,  # X-axis tick labels
    "ytick.labelsize": 20,  # Y-axis tick labels
    "axes.labelsize": 24,   # Axis titles
    "legend.fontsize": 18,  # Legend font size
    "axes.titleweight": "bold"  # Axis title font weight
})

plot = plot.facet(row="time")
plot.plot()

plot.theme(): This method accepts a dictionary of matplotlib-style parameters to customize various elements of the plot. I have added some general values you can use.

Thanks so much @Lucas! You just made my day a lot better! I really did not find it in the docs. How could I miss that! Again thank you!

@mr.raccoon. No problem, is something I really struggle previously too!
